# Why [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")] not work?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, .net-6.0, swashbuckle

I use Swagger in my .NET 6.0 API, and I want to use different SwaggerEndpoint to group my API.
Here is the code I set in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Blog API",
        Version = "v1"
    });

    options.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Blog API",
        Version = "v2"
    });
}

// ...
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");

        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Blog API V1");
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "Blog API V2");
    });
}
```

And I set Attribute `[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")]` or v1 in controller. 
In swagger UI, when I select the option, it cannot filter my API (It still display all API both in two options).
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I remove this setting in swagger, and ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")] is working!

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => {
    // remove this setting
    options.DocInclusionPredicate((name, api) => true);
});
```

The setting means always show all API when select the definition on upper right corner.

Sorry about it's hard to paste all `Program.cs` code (too long) in my question. Hope this answer can help someone.